# Bootstrap columns stacking vertically and not horizontally

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have a row divided into 3 columns using `col-sm-4`. Now i expect this row to be divided horizontally into three parts. But it's divided vertically.

See on [Jsfillde](http://jsfiddle.net/3uzuf2j7/)

Here's my code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"  style="padding:13px 15px;">
        <div class="pull-left span4">
            <a href=""><img src="themes/custom/img/logo.png" width="120" alt="logo"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right span4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">One</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">Two</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">Three</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have kept a logo on the left side and on the right side there is a row that i want to divide horizontally in 3 parts.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code works just fine. The `.col-sm-*` classes are applied for width 768px and above. If you want  make this three divs always horizontally, you have to use classes `.col-xs-4` in your case. [Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3uzuf2j7/1/)

Futher reading - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: Update for Bootstrap v4:  the col-xs-* classes have been replaced with col-* (e.g. col-4) for xs viewport sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and was at my wits end. Then I refreshed the browser and it worked.

Comment: not sure why this got o many downvotes. it could really help someone